# How to make text bold with sweetalert in 2018?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I saw that you could use the content option, but im not really sure how to go about that right now I have something like:

`swal({title: 'hello', text: 'hello ${<strong>{name}</strong>}', icon: 'success' })`

Comment: Try the same way that you used in 2017. It should work. ;)

Comment: I tried the html true and all that , but no success

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the GitHub Issues, you should set a content and insert the text within it:

```
var name = "Stack Overflow";
var content = document.createElement('div');
    content.innerHTML = 'Hello <strong>'+ name +'</strong>';

    swal({
        title: 'Hello',
        content: content,
        icon: "success",
    })
```

Answer (score 8):

Or, you can use [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) - the supported fork of original SweetAlert:

```js
Swal.fire({
  html: 'Overengineering is <strong>a bad thing</strong>'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

PS. notice that SweetAlert2 is a little bit different from SweetAlert, check the simple migration guide: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2